# Entity Framework 4.1 Fluent API property

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

When configuring a property (Name is String, RowVersion is Byte)

This works:

```
Me.Property(Function(t) t.Name).IsRequired().IsFixedLength.HasMaxLength(10)
```

But this gives me an error:

```
Me.Property(Function(t) t.RowVersion).IsRequired().IsFixedLength().HasMaxLength(8)
```

The error is:

> 'IsFixedLength' is not a member of
>   'System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.PrimitivePropertyConfiguration'

Any suggestions why?

Answer (score 1):

[Because it isn't.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.modelconfiguration.configuration.primitivepropertyconfiguration%28v=VS.103%29.aspx) You can call `IsFixedLength()` on a string, but not on a `TIMESTAMP`. Ditto for `HasMaxLength()`. What would you expect the DB to do with such a configuration, anyway?